# phpexcel returns blank excel file using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpexcel

I have created a phpexcel script that prints reports in excel. The test code was ok but when I added some ajax for onclick event in a form, it returns blank excel file. This is my phpexcel code:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

$dept = "";
$from = "";
$to = "";
set_time_limit(0);

$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$from = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['from']));
$to = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['to']));

try{
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM emptb WHERE Department = :dept ORDER BY id ASC");
$query->bindParam(':dept',$dept);
$query->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//set default font
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setName('Verdana');
//set titles
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1','EMPLOYEE ATTENDANCE LOGS');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetUp()->setRowstoRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1,3);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(29.25);
//merge cells
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:T1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C4:D4');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E8:F8');
//set text alignment
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setSize(18);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('#333');
//set column width
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(6.14);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(0.67);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(10.86);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(1.43);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(9.71);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(1.43);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(10.7);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(1.57);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(9);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(0.58);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(0.92);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(9);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(1.71);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(2.43);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(6.14);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(1.71);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('R')->setWidth(9.29);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('S')->setWidth(4);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('T')->setWidth(0.67);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('U')->setWidth(0.67);

$rowCount = 4;
while($row = $query->fetch())
{               
    $rowTitle = $rowCount + 2;
    $rowTitle1 = $rowCount + 4;
    //data label
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C'.($rowCount).':D'.($rowCount));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,'ID No:');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C'.($rowTitle).':D'.($rowTitle));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowTitle,'Name:');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I'.($rowCount).':J'.($rowCount));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount,'Dept:');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle1)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C'.($rowTitle1).':D'.($rowTitle1));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle1)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowTitle1,'Section:');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowTitle1)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('I'.($rowTitle1).':J'.($rowTitle1));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowTitle1)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowTitle1,'Line:');
    //data contents
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E'.($rowCount).':G'.($rowCount));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,$row['EmpID']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E'.($rowTitle).':S'.($rowTitle));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowTitle,$row['Lastname'] . ', ' . $row['Firstname']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle)->getFont()->setName('Arial');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('L'.($rowCount).':S'.($rowCount));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount,$row['Department']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowTitle1,$row['SectionName']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setName('Arial');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowTitle1,$row['LineName']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setSize(12);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L'.$rowTitle1)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $rowCount++;

    try{
        $subquery = $con->prepare("SELECT  c.dt,a.TimeIn,a.LunchOut,a.LunchIn,a.RNDOUT FROM cal c LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.ValidDate = c.dt
        AND a.EmpID = :id WHERE c.dt BETWEEN DATE('2015-08-01') AND DATE('2015-08-30') GROUP BY c.dt ORDER BY c.dt ASC");
        $subquery->bindParam(':id',$row['EmpID']);
        $subquery->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
    $titleRow = $rowCount + 5;
    $rowCount += 6;
    while($subrow = $subquery->fetch())
    {

        if($subrow['TimeIn'] == "00:00:00")
        {
            $TimeIn = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $TimeIn = $subrow['TimeIn'];
        }

        if($subrow['LunchOut']=="00:00:00")
        {
            $LunchOut = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $LunchOut = $subrow['LunchOut'];
        }

        if($subrow['LunchIn']=="00:00:00")
        {
            $LunchIn = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $LunchIn = $subrow['LunchIn'];
        }

        if($subrow['RNDOUT']=="00:00:00")
        {
            $TimeOut = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $TimeOut = $subrow['RNDOUT'];
        }
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setSize(11);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$titleRow,'Date');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setSize(11);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$titleRow,'TimeIn');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G'.($titleRow).':H'.($titleRow));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setSize(11);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$titleRow,'LunchOut');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setSize(11);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$titleRow,'LunchIn');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$titleRow)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setSize(11);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$titleRow)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$titleRow,'TimeOut');


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,$subrow['dt']);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,$TimeIn);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,$LunchOut);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,$LunchIn);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$rowCount)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M'.$rowCount)->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount,$TimeOut);
        $rowCount++;
     }
     $rowCount+=1;
     $newRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak('A'.$newRow,PHPExcel_WorkSheet::BREAK_ROW);
    }
    $excelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
    header('Content-Type:application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$dept.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control:max-age=0');
    $excelWriter->save('php://output');
```

And here is my ajax function that somehow returns empty value

```
function myFunction()
   {
   var idept = $("#cmbdept[name=dept]").val();
   var first = $("#from[name=from]").val();
   var second = $("#to[name=to]").val();

    $.ajax({
    url: "printreport.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: {dept: idept,from: first,to: second},
    cache: false,
    global: false;
    success: function(data)
    {
        //alert('Report is printing');
        window.open('http://localhost/hrtms/printreport.php','_blank');
    }
    });
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you called `printreport.php` twice.
in first call (in ajax), that make excel file.
in second call (in `window.open`), that has no parameters.
that's why return empty file, I guess.

How about make real file in `printreport.php`, and `window.open` created file's web path?

this is my code when i was make excel file through phpexcel.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xlsObj, 'Excel2007');
$filename = 'FILENAME_WHAT_YOU_WANT';
$file_full_name = 'DATA_PATH_WHAT_YOU_WANT' . '/' . $filename;
$objWriter->save($file_full_name);
```

P.S i'm not good at English, if you feel weird, please forgive me.

-----appended for more-----
in PHP for return file path after create excel file

```
if(file_exists($file_full_name)){
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>false, 'export_path'=>'/temp_upload/' . $filename));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>true, 'error_msg' => 'Export Failed'));
}
```

in javascript for link to created excel file

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '/menu/audience/exportActivity',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'type': 'post',
    'data': data,
    success: function(r){
        //for loading animation to hide
        $('body').find('div.loading.all').css('display', 'none');
        if(!r.error){
            location.href = r.export_path;
        }
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){
        $('body').find('div.loading.all').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

that's my code when i coded

Comment: My problem is in the ajax part not in the phpexcel part because I already have that code in my phpexcel.

Comment: I was return created excel file's web path, and link to created file in ajax success function. I'm sorry if my answer can't helpful.